# JSP UI Builder like ASP .NET forms creator in Visual Studio

Tags: jsp, editor

I have come across a Web UI form editor in Visual Studio 2005+ which helps in creating the aspx forms. Similarly is there any creator for web forms for JSP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can use **IBM Websphere Studio (Rational Software)**  which have this facility. But I'm not sure if it is available for free.

---

Try this link Try this http://www.myeclipseide.com/module-htmlpages-display-pid-12.html